# Is there a standard/common practice for documenting an event handler?

Tags: .net, documentation

This is something that causes me some pause from time to time. It seems like I need to provide 
a description for `sender` and `e`. Since I cannot think of anything particularly meaningful I'd prefer to delete the two `param` elements.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Fired when the destination project is updated.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void UpdateDestinations(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use GhostDoc to do all the heavy lifting for you (like the parameters documentation for example) so that you can concentrate on providing meaningful information for the remaining elements (the summary in that case).

Comment: I know this thread is old but out of curiosity is there a standard way of documenting these parameters without the use of GhostDoc.

Comment: You could check how they are documented in the MSDN and use this as a convention for your development